# Implement a flatten layer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to implement a flatten layer using TensorFlow 2.2.0. I am following the instructions from Geron's book (2nd ed).
As for a flatten layer, I first try to get the batch input shape and compute the new shape.
But I have met this problem with tensor dimensions: `TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]
assert input_shape == (28, 28)

class MyFlatten(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, batch_input_shape):
        super().build(batch_input_shape) 

    def call(self, X):
        X_shape = tf.shape(X)
        batch_size = X_shape[0]
        new_shape = tf.TensorShape([batch_size, X_shape[1]*X_shape[2]])
        return tf.reshape(X, new_shape)

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config}

## works fine on this example
MyFlatten()(X_train[:10])

## fail when building a model
input_ = keras.layers.Input(shape=[28, 28])
fltten_ = MyFlatten()(input_)
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu")(fltten_)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu")(hidden1)
output = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(hidden2)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_], outputs=[output])
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to create a [`tf.TensorShape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape), that will only work when all dimensions of the tensor are known, which in practice will be only on eager mode, so it model compilation will fail. Simply reshape like this:

```py
def call(self, X):
    X_shape = tf.shape(X)
    batch_size = X_shape[0]
    new_shape = [batch_size, X_shape[1] * X_shape[2]]
    return tf.reshape(X, new_shape)
```

Or, more generally, you can just do:

```py
def call(self, X):
    X_shape = tf.shape(X)
    batch_size = X_shape[0]
    new_shape = [batch_size, tf.math.reduce_prod(X_shape[1:])]
    return tf.reshape(X, new_shape)
```

[`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) would also accept something like `new_shape = [batch_size, -1]`, but I think that may make the size of the flattened dimension unknown depending on the case. On the other hand, the opposite thing, `new_shape = [-1, tf.math.reduce_prod(X_shape[1:])]`, should work fine too.

Btw, I assume you are doing this as an exercise and already know this, but just for reference there is already a [`Flatten`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Flatten) layer in Keras (and you can check its [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L597-L684)).